# Access - How to bring space from bottom of report up when collapse function true

Tags: ms-access

I have code that collapses my report dependent upon how many service users are on the report.  Any more than one and the space expands.  My issue is that when condensed everything moves up except for the footer and this sometimes produces an unneeded page when printing.  The collapse function reads the control's tag and if matched then will trigger that control to be moved.  I have tried tagging the footers (report and page) and the controls within the footers to be the same as the controls within the details section.  I thought that would help to pull it up along with the controls but it doesnt.  Worst case scenario, I can just scrap the entire collapse function since it isnt required, but I like the aesthetics of the function.

Basically, the code moves everything up but doesnt reduce the *details* section along with it.

I have added the code and some supporting images. Image one shows the frame that collapses (highlighted in yellow).  It is that exact amount of space that appears at the end of the case note between the end of the detail section and the beginning of the footer (image 2).  When the space is expanded, there is no space between the end of the report users credentials and the page number.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
'''
'Collapse Client Section

 Dim ctl As Control      '// This sets the variable 'ctl' for use below

If IsNull(Me.txtClientID2) And IsNull(Me.txtClientID3) And IsNull(Me.txtClientID4) And IsNull(Me.txtClientID5) _
And IsNull(Me.txtClientID6) And IsNull(Me.txtClientID7) And IsNull(Me.txtClientID8) And IsNull(Me.txtClientID9) _
And IsNull(Me.txtClientID10) Then

Me.lblIndicator.Caption = "--"
Else
Me.lblIndicator.Caption = "++"
End If


    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
     '// This 'For' statement repeats the following code (until its corresponding 'Next') for each
    '   control in the current form individually.
    
         '// SECTION 1 - EXPANDING/COLLAPSING THE SECTION/SUBFORM
        '
        If InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "ExpandCollapseSection1") <> 0 Then
         '// This checks to see if the control has an "ExpandCollapseSection1" anywhere within
        '   its tag property.
        '// For every control that has, the following (until its corresponding 'End If') happens.
        
            If Me.ActiveControl Is ctl Then
             '// Before we get to expanding/collapsing, any 'to be collapsed' control must be
            '   inactive, since you can't hide an active control.
            '// This checks to see if any control in the collapse section is active.
            '// If it is, the following happens.

                 '// The next control after the expand/collapse section of my form is made active.
                '// In this case, it's txtAddress. Set it to anything you want.
            End If
            
            If lblIndicator.Caption = "--" Then
                ctl.Visible = False
            Else
                ctl.Visible = True
            End If
             '// This 'If' statement checks whether the indicator is -.
            '// If it is a -, then control(s) (subform/section) hides.
            '// However, if it is not a - (but a +), the control(s) is shown.
            
        End If      '// Ends the 'If InStr' statement
        
         '// SECTION 2 - MOVING ITEMS BELOW DOWN/UP
        '
        If InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "ItemBelowECSection1") <> 0 Then
         '// This checks to see if the control has an "ItemBelowECSection1" anywhere within
        '   its tag property. If it does, the following happens for it.
        
            If lblIndicator.Caption = "--" Then
                ctl.Top = ctl.Top - frameECSection1.Height
            Else
                'ctl.Top = ctl.Top + frameECSection1.Height
            End If
             '// If the Indicator is -, the control moves up the height of the section's frame
            '   or the subform. Otherwise, it moves down the height of the frame/subform.
            
        End If
        
    Next        '// Ends the 'For' Statement
    
     '
    '// SECTION 3 - INDICATOR CHANGE
    '
    If lblIndicator.Caption = "--" Then
        lblIndicator.Caption = "++"
    Else
        lblIndicator.Caption = "--"
    End If
     '// If the indicator is a -, it's changed to a +; otherwise it's changed to a -.
    
    Set ctl = Nothing      '//  Resets the variable 'ctl'
'''
```

Comment: You want the page number to move up? Page number should always be in same location on each page, regardless of what is or isn't above it.

Comment: @June7 is right. Perhaps you could create a _group_ with a footer simulating the page footer.

Comment: If you have one record only, you can use the _report_ footer and skip the page footer.